# Benchmarking: RawOrigin::Root as AccountId

Tags: account, root, benchmark, origin

One of benchmarked extrinsic of custom pallet requires `Root` sender (or Sudo), uses `pallet_assets` from runtime trait implementation (no coupling here). To verify I'm using `balance()` method to confirm asset is present. One of inputs for that is `AccountId`, so I need to convert `RawOrigin::Root` to `AccountId` somehow. Thanks.

##### Pallet

```
//--- snip ---
#[frame_support::pallet]
pub mod pallet {
    #[pallet::config]
    pub trait Config: frame_system::Config {
//--- snip ---
        type AssertCreateUpdateOrigin: EnsureOrigin<<Self as frame_system::Config>::Origin>;
//--- snip ---
    }
//--- snip ---
    #[pallet::call]
    impl<T: Config> Pallet<T> {
        #[pallet::weight(100_000)]
        pub fn extrinsic_call(origin: OriginFor<T>) -> DispatchResult 
        {
            T::AssetCreateUpdateOrigin::ensure_origin(origin)?;
        //--- snip ---
        }
//--- snip ---
    }
}
```

##### Benchmark

```
benchmarks! {
    extrinsic_call {
        let b in 0 .. u8::MAX;
        let account: T::AccountId = RawOrigin::Root.into(); // <<<--- THIS NEEDS TO WORK SOMEHOW 
        let id = H160::from_slice(&[bu8; 20]);
    }: _(RawOrigin::Root, id)
    verify {
        assert_eq!(0, T::AssetManager::balance(u128::from_be_bytes([bu8; 16]), &account));
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you maybe post the code of your extrinsic and the benchmark or test that you try to write?

Comment: created minimal example

Answer (score 2):

When writing benchmarks which use `EnsureOrigin`, you should be using the specific helper function `successful_origin` which is meant for exactly this scenario:

```
/// Some sort of check on the origin is performed by this object.
pub trait EnsureOrigin<OuterOrigin> {
    /// A return type.
    type Success;

    /// Perform the origin check.
    fn ensure_origin(o: OuterOrigin) -> Result<Self::Success, BadOrigin> {
        Self::try_origin(o).map_err(|_| BadOrigin)
    }

    /// Perform the origin check.
    fn try_origin(o: OuterOrigin) -> Result<Self::Success, OuterOrigin>;

    /// Returns an outer origin capable of passing `try_origin` check.
    ///
    /// ** Should be used for benchmarking only!!! **
    #[cfg(feature = "runtime-benchmarks")]
    fn successful_origin() -> OuterOrigin;
}
```

In this case, you do not need to assume how a user has implemented the `EnsureOrigin` trait, since they will be required to provide an answer to how to pass this check.

Now, one implementation of this COULD be `RawOrigin::Root`, but then you DEFINITELY cannot assume that you can create an `AccountId` from this.

It says to me your logic is fundamentally flawed, since an `Origin != Account`. Only one of the possible origins, specifically `Origin::Signed` can be resolved into an `AccountId`.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to ensure that `AssertCreateUpdateOrigin` resolves into an `AccountId`, consider placing a bound on the `Success` type:

```
type AssertCreateUpdateOrigin: EnsureOrigin<<Self as frame_system::Config>::Origin, Success=Self::AccountId>;
```

You can then use:

```
let account = AssertCreateUpdateOrigin::ensure_origin(origin)?;
```

This will either bail with an error or properly populate `account` with an value determined by the origin. As @shawn says, it is up to the implementer of `AssertCreateUpdateOrigin` to ensure that a successful origin actually exists for the purpose of benchmarking and you can get access to such an origin by using `AssetCreateUpdateOrigin::successful_origin()`.